# How can I combine the code in my Search Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am currently working on Search using this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised?autoplay=true). Everything works great, and I am able to search for various resources from two different tables (School & District).

However, I am currently calling two separate search methods from my controller, and combining the search results into one array in my controller.

Is there anyway to combine the code in my Model?

Search Controller

```
def show
  @search = Search.find(params[:id])

  @searches = []

  ///Calls two separate search methods from my model and combines the results.
  (@searches << @search.district_resources).flatten!
  (@searches << @search.school_resources).flatten!
  @searches = @searches.uniq

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @searches.to_json }
  end
end
```

Method

```
//How can I combine this code to search for values in both tables?
def district_resources
  @district_resources ||= find_district_resources
end

def school_resources
  @school_resources ||= find_school_resources
end

def find_school_resources
  school_resources = SchoolResource.order(:name)
  school_resources = school_resources.where(state_id: state_id) if state_id.present?
end

def find_district_resources
  district_resources = DistrictResource.order(:name)
  district_resources = district_resources.where(state_id: state_id) if state_id.present?
end
```

Comment: How are the two models related? Are you using STI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new method to your model:

```
def district_and_school_resources
  (district_resources + school_resources).uniq.sort_by(&:name)
end
```

And use it in your controller like this:

```
def show
  resources = Search.find(params[:id]).district_and_school_resources

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => resources.to_json }
  end
end
```